# Video Upload using formidable in Nodejs, Error found: post 404 / 502

Tags: node.js, ajax, video, upload

I'm uploading video file from local to server and then I'll be uploading it to cdn,
the issue i'm facing is my code is running well on local but its not working when i patch it to server.

Here is my code

commonJs

```
$("#uploadVideo").click(function (e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('Videofile');
    var previewUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
    $(".video").attr("src", previewUrl);

    var videotype = "video/mp4";
    var file_data = $("#Videofile").prop("files")[0];


    if (!file_data.type.match(videotype)) {
        return "alert('Please upload mp4 files')"
    } else {
        var metadata = {
            'content-type': 'video/mp4',
            'size': file_data.size,
            'uploaded': new Date(),
        }
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("file_data").text("File Content: " + reader.result); // Show the file content
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file_data);
        file_data.onloadedmetadata = function () {
            alert("Meta data for audio loaded");
        };
    };

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", file_data)
    form_data.append("metdata", metadata)
    for (var key of form_data.entries()) {
        console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
    }

    if (form_data != undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            url: "/api/recordvideo",
            data: form_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $(".video").attr("src", result.videolink);
                    alert("Successfully Uploaded Video");
                    console.log("Successfully Uploaded Video");
                } else {
                    alert("Error on Uploading Video");
                    console.log("Error on Uploading Video");
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log("error");
            }

        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

ServerSide

```
app.post('/api/recordvideo',Api.recordvideo);

var Upload = require('gcs-resumable-upload');
ApiService.recordvideo = function (req, res) {

var db = req.db;
console.log("came in cloudupload");
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
var filesdata;
form.keepExtensions = true;
form.multiples = false;

form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
    file.path = 'public/demo/' + file.name;
    console.log("fileBegin: " + JSON.stringify(file));
});

form.on('file', function (name, file){
    console.log('Uploaded ' + JSON.stringify(file));
    var path = file.path;    
    console.log("came in cloud3 :" + JSON.stringify(path));
});

form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log("came in cloud0" + JSON.stringify(files));
    filesdata = files;
});


console.log("came in cloud2");
form.on('end', function (fields, files) {

    var userid = appconfig.ObjectID(appconfig.decrypt(req.signedCookies['gid']));
    var path = this.openedFiles[0].path;    

    console.log("came in cloud3 :" + JSON.stringify(path));
    fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(Upload.upload({ bucket: '******', file: path, metadata: { contentType: this.openedFiles[0].type } }))
        .on('finish', function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully Uploaded Video :" + JSON.stringify(response));
            res.send({ "status": false, "videolink": "https://****/****/" + filesdata.file.name });

            });

        });
    //res.send({ "status": false, "err": null });
}
```

At start atleast it was uploading to server folder & then in chrome developers tool it used to give response: {readystate : 4, . . . }

And now, I made some changes then it doesnt even hit my api, After few seconds it  gives error in chrome developer tools 404() / 502 ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got the solution, Previously I was using **gcs-resumable-upload** module to upload, but now I tried with **'@google-cloud/storage'** module through which I was able to upload upto 9mb.

```js
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    var db = req.db;
    console.log("came in cloudupload");
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var filesdata;
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.multiples = false;

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        filesdata = files;
    });

    form.on('end', function (fields, files) {
    var userid = appconfig.ObjectID(appconfig.decrypt(req.signedCookies['gid']));
        var path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        const storage = new Storage({
            keyFilename: 'gcloudcred.json'
        });
    const myBucket = storage.bucket('onfvideo');
    myBucket.upload(path).then((resp) => {
            console.log('uploaded to' + resp);
            res.send({ "status": true, "err": null });
        }).catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
                res.send({ "status": false, "err": null });
            });
        });
    };
```

The Limitation of 9mb I was facing due to .netframework data-transfer limit which i was able to resolve using

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="7483648" />
</system.web>
```

Method 2: Using xhr calling RestApi 
1. Generated Access token using google-auto-auth module 
2. XMLHttpRequest

```js
var fileInput = $("#Videofile").prop("files")[0];
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o?uploadType=media&name=" + fileInput.name;
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', url, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'video/mp4');
http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
http.send(fileInput);
http.onprogress = function (ev) {
            if (ev.lengthComputable) {
                var percentage = Math.round((ev.loaded / ev.total) * 100);
                console.log("percent " + percentage + '%');
            }else {
              console.log("Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown");
            }
        }
http.onloadstart = function (ev) {console.log("start")}
http.onloadend = function (ev) {}
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
           alert("Successfully Uploaded Video");
        }
 }
```